# rails3 jquery autocomplete getting and passing array

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

This may seem like an easy problem to most of you, but it's been troubling me all day.

I'm trying to implement messaging system. I want to be able to send message to multiple people. for this to happen i need help with two things:
Firstly, data-delimeter doesn't work. I'm guessing i just don't know how to correclt write it with simple form.

**messages_controller.rb**

```
  autocomplete :profile, :firstname, :extra_data => [:user_id]
```

**messsages/form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for @message do |f|

      = f.input :profile_firstname, :url => autocomplete_profile_firstname_messages_path,
:'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true,
 :as => :autocomplete, :update_elements => {:recipients_ids => '#user_id'}
```

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7tlapbrdyupxhr/compose.png]

as you can see in the image, data-dalimeter doesn't work ;/

And secondly, does anyone know how to pass an array of user_ids with autocomplete ?
In my messages model i have :recipient_ids[] array to which i need to pass user_id trough the form.

It would be really amazing if someone could point me to the right direction. THANK YOU !!